# how to estimate parameters of mixture of 2 exponential random variables (ideally in Python)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statistics, estimation, exponential-distribution

Imagine a simulation experiment in which the output is *n* total numbers, where *k* of them are sampled from an exponential random variable with rate *a* and *n-k* are sampled from an exponential random variable with rate *b*. The constraints are that 0 < *a ≤ b* and 0 ≤ *k* ≤ *n*, but *a*, *b*, and *k* are all unknown. Further, because of details of the simulation experiment, when *a << b*, *k* ≈ 0, and when *a = b*, *k* ≈ *n*/2.

My goal is to estimate either *a* or *b* (don't care about *k*, and I don't need to estimate both *a* and *b*: just one of the two is fine). From speculation, it seems as though estimating just *b* might be the easiest path (when *a << b*, there is pretty much nothing to use to estimate *a* and plenty to estimate *b*, and when *a = b*, both there is still plenty to estimate *b*). I want to do it in Python ideally, but I am open to any free software.

My first approach was to use `sklearn.optimize` to optimize a likelihood function where, for each number in my dataset, I compute P(X=x) for an exponential with rate *a*, compute the same for an exponential with rate *b*, and simply choose the larger of the two:

```
from sys import stdin
from math import exp,log
from scipy.optimize import fmin
DATA = None

def pdf(x,l): # compute P(X=x) for an exponential rv X with rate l
    return l*exp(-1*l*x)

def logML(X,la,lb): # compute the log-ML of data points X given two exponentials with rates la and lb where la < lb
    ml = 0.0
    for x in X:
       ml += log(max(pdf(x,la),pdf(x,lb)))
    return ml

def f(x): # objective function to minimize
    assert DATA is not None, "DATA cannot be None"
    la,lb = x
    if la > lb: # force la <= lb
        return float('inf')
    elif la <= 0 or lb <= 0:
        return float('inf') # force la and lb > 0
    return -1*logML(DATA,la,lb)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    DATA = [float(x) for x in stdin.read().split()] # read input data
    Xbar = sum(DATA)/len(DATA) # compute mean
    x0 = [1/Xbar,1/Xbar] # start with la = lb = 1/mean
    result = fmin(f,x0,disp=DISP)
    print("ML Rates: la = %f and lb = %f" % tuple(result))
```

This unfortunately didn't work very well. For some selections of the parameters, it's within an order of magnitude, but for others, it's absurdly off. Given my problem (with its constraints) and my goal of estimating the larger parameter of the two exponentials (without caring about the smaller parameter nor the number of points that came from either), any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I posted the question in more general statistical terms on the stats Stack Exchange, and it got an answer:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/291642/how-to-estimate-parameters-of-mixture-of-2-exponential-random-variables-ideally

Also, I tried the following, which worked decently well:

First, for every single integer percentile (1st percentile, 2nd percentile, ..., 99th percentile), I compute the estimate of *b* using the quantile closed-form equation (where the *i*-th quantile is the (*i* *100)-th percentile) for an exponential distribution (the *i*-th quantile = −ln(1 − *i*) / λ, so λ = −ln(1 − *i*) / (*i*-th quantile)). The result is a list where each *i*-th element corresponds to the *b* estimate using the (*i*+1)-th percentile.

Then, I perform peak-calling on this list using the Python implementation of the Matlab peak-calling function. Then, I take the list of resulting peaks and return the minimum. It seems to work fairly well.

I will implement the EM solution in the Stack Exchange post as well and see which works better.

EDIT: I implemented the EM solution, and it seems to work decently well in my simulations (*n* = 1000, various *a* and *b*).